# Compiling Issues in ARM terminal

Tags: c++, linux, qt, arm

I have compiled my project in terminal on one system, and then moved the project to my raspberry pi with Ubuntu Mate. When I try to run/execute the program I get this error:

> 'symbol lookup error: ./classwizard: undefined symbol:
>   _ZN7QWidget8qwsEventEP8QSEvent'

Comment: And is Qt development packages installed on the target? The correct version?

Comment: No it is not. 
Should it be?

Comment: I don't know, are you *building* your application *on* the target platform? Then yes you need the development packages. If you only *run* your already built program, then you don't need the development packages, just the "normal" non-development packages.

Comment: Assume you're cross-compiling the binary, then you probably need to install the required packages on RaspberryPi to run your binary.

Comment: How would I do that? Or should I just install all of Qt on the ARM/Pi?

Comment: @Mine forgot to tag you before ^^

Comment: @torontosam Yes, you should install the needed library (e.g. libqtgui) on RPi, then it should work

Comment: I just decided to install Qt 4 entirely, but I am still getting the same error. @Mine

Comment: I rebuilt Qt the same way I did on my desktop to cross compile with ARM